Предикат подсписка в Prolog
Здравствуйте я пытаюсь определить предикат в Strawberry Prolog: по условию :предикат определяющий является  список подсписком исходного списка если элементы подсписка находятся в том же порядке что и в исходном списке  sublist(Sub  , Lst) Например : исходный список [a, b, c, d], при проверке этих списков : [a, b] Yes; [b, c] Yes ; [c, d] Yes; [a, b, c] Yes ; [b, c , d] Yes; а если [a, c] - No и т.д.
вот что получается, только оно не работает, как нужно
sublist([], _).
sublist([H|SubTail], [H|LstTail]) :-
    sublist(SubTail, LstTail).
sublist(Sub, [_|LstTail]) :-
    sublist(Sub, LstTail).
?- sublist([a, b], [a, b, c, d]).  
?- sublist([b, c], [a, b, c, d]).  
?- sublist([c, d], [a, b, c, d]). 
?- sublist([a, b, c], [a, b, c, d]). 
?- sublist([b, c, d], [a, b, c, d]). 
?- sublist([a, c], [a, b, c, d]).


Смог сделать 1 рабочий вариант: ` sub_start([], ).
sub_start([H|T1], [H|T2]) :-
sub_start(T1, T2).
sublist(Sub, List) :-
sub_start(Sub, List), !.
sublist(Sub, [|T]) :-
sublist(Sub, T).
?- sublist([b, c], [a, b, c, d]).
?- sublist([c, b, a], [a, b, c, d]). `

Рабочий вариант добавьте ответом. Либо, если в нем что-то не устраивает - внесите в вопрос, и укажите, что с ним не так.
